# Highcharts Scatter type chart markers are not matching with legend symbols

Tags: highcharts, scatter

I have a series of highcharts graphs in an app. Newest graph we add was a scatter type chart.

Unfortunately its markers are not matching up with legend symbols. Please find an attachment showing the issue.

I am unable to reproduce this in a separate file as it works fine when I do that. I have example of how it behaves within the application.
We are using highcharts 9.0.1 version
[image]
any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Please give some sample code for recreate this issue, here is [example](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/je7kwyLb/) with scatter series in 9.0.1 version Highcharts and everything look good. Could you provide more details, on which devices you use?

Comment: it was really hard to build a sample as we have a singe chart rendering for multiple chart types with lot of variant options. Line/Area/Scatter. What has happened was previous Highcharts.seriesTypes.line.prototype.drawLegendSymbol = Highcharts.seriesTypes.column.prototype.drawLegendSymbol; was conflicting with scatter charts. Managed to sort it out.